# Backslash in a Tcl regexp

Tags: regex, tcl

Regarding the regexp in TCL, if I use the following regexp:

```
regexp "helloworld\[\\s]+.name."
```

to match the following output:

```
helloworld  (name)
```

it works. but I wonder if I need to add "`\`" in front of the "`]`", I saw some code made by others, they did not close the "`]`" with "`\`", I want to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one reason might be what Utkanos explained, the other one might be due to a Tcl-specific behavior: the `[` character has special meaning in places where command substitution is allowed.  Observe:

```
% proc foo {} { return y }
% puts x[foo]z
xyz
```

Consequently, when you're working with a regex in Tcl (either by trying to specify it literally, or construct in at runtime etc), you have to think how the string which forms this regex will be treated by Tcl.

That's why most of the time you see the characters of a regex passed directly to the `regexp` command grouped using the curly braces, `{` and `}`: it inhibits (most of) Tcl's substitutions and hence allows to write the regex specification "as is", almost in its plain syntax, without any escaping.

But this obviously does not play well for cases when you want to dynamically construct the specification (say, embed the contents of a variable in there).  Usually people resort to group the regex characters using double quotes consequently needing to do special escaping to prevent certain Tcl's substitutions.  More clean approach might be to construct the pattern using the `append` command.

More info on grouping is [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl3.html), [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl4.html) and [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl5.html).

As to finding the book on the Internet, ["Mastering Regular Expressions"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do) is what usually considered to be *the book* on the subject.

As a side note, in your particular example the square brackets are not needed at all: in regexes, they are used to create "character ranges" — patterns that match a single characters out of the specified range, — and in your case the range consists of exactly one (meta) character defined to match a single whitespace character in the input.  So in this particular case the pattern `helloworld\s+.name.` would do just fine.

Comment: To clarify the last point, the matching should be written `regexp {helloworld\s+.name.} $someString`, with a (largely) simple regular expression in `{` brace `}` characters.

Comment: And to further clarify for the OP why `]` is not escaped: it has no special meaning to the parser because at the time the parser sees this closing bracket while it's parsing the string grouped by double quotes it did not yet see any open `[` and so there's no nested group to complete and process.  You still might escape that `]` if you feel it's more readable -- it won't confuse the parser.

Answer (score 0):

No, because you are using `[` with its special meaning, i.e. to define a range. You would escape it with a backslash only if you wanted to match a literal `[`. Backslashes are used to escape characters which otherwise invoke special behaviour in REGEXP.

(Javascript)

```
var str = "[hello]";
str.match(/[a-z]+/); //resultant array: ['hello']
str.match(/\[[a-z]+\]/); //resultant array: ['[hello]']
```

Comment: Alas, this is a Tcl question, not a Javascript question. This matters because the answer has to do with how Tcl handles metacharacters.

Comment: Condescension aside, since many REGEX quesitons can be answered with reference to general REGEX grammar rather than the specific environment in which the user is operating, I thought I'd try to help out.

Comment: I'm not being condescending. The questioner is asking about quoting, and that's recognizably an issue that relates to the _other_ tag on the question. (Hey, you've not yet been voted down…)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this expression is what you want:

```
regexp {helloworld\s+.name.} $the_string
```

You don't need any square bracket at all.